# ¿Cómo contar la frecuencia de datos de una columna?

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo el siguiente dataframe (una muestra, por que el original tiene 17 columnas 13966 filas):

| pais | categoria | marca |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chile | frutas | riosur |
| chile | frutas | rioking |
| chile | frutas | minuto verde |
| chile | snack | evercrisp |
| chile | snack | marco polo |
| chile | snack | marco polo |
| chile | bebida | ccu |
| chile | bebida | coca-cola |
| chile | bebida | ccu |
| chile | bebida | fruna |
| chile | sanck | ticka |

necesito poder contar la frecuencia unica de aparicion de las marcas agrupado por pais y por categoria, dado que hay más de un país, para poder graficarlo despues.

intenté hacer los siguiente:

```
datos <- df %>%
 group_by(pais,categoria) %>%
 summarise(marca = count(unique(marca), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 ungroup()
```

pero no me esta corriendo el resultado, agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: En R base la forma más simple es `table(df$pais, df$categoria)`

Answer (score 1):

Te vendría bien usar la función `length`, la cual combinada con `unique`, te retornara el vector de frecuencia única de aparición

```
Datos %>%
  group_by(pais, categoria) %>%
  summarise(marca = length(unique(marca))) %>%
  ungroup()
```